# LINQ 'query syntax' -- where clause filtering against List of int

Tags: c#, linq

Struggling on how to get this filter to work:

```
  var categoryIDs = new List<int>();
              categoryIDs.Add(2);
              categoryIDs.Add(3);

             var dbContacts = (from cnt in _db.Contacts
                join ucc in _db.UserContactCategories on cnt.id equals ucc.ContactID
                join cat in _db.Categories on ucc.CatDescID equals cat.id
                where categoryIDs.Equals(cnt.id)
                select new {cnt.id,
                    cnt.GivenName,
                    cnt.SurName                         
                }).ToList();
```

Getting this error message:

> Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types

Comment: you are are trying to compare a `List<int>` to an `int`, which won't work. Are you actually trying to use the equivalent of the sql `IN` operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are are trying to compare a `List<int>` to an `int`, which won't work.

If you're looking to get all contacts that are in your hard coded `List<int>`, just use the `Contains` method.

```
var categoryIDs = new List<int>();
              categoryIDs.Add(2);
              categoryIDs.Add(3);

             var dbContacts = (from cnt in _db.Contacts
                join ucc in _db.UserContactCategories on cnt.id equals ucc.ContactID
                join cat in _db.Categories on ucc.CatDescID equals cat.id
                where categoryIDs.Contains(cat.id)
                select new {cnt.id,
                    cnt.GivenName,
                    cnt.SurName                         
                }).ToList();
```